# string manipulation in python to convert the case of a word that comes next to "caps lock"

Tags: python

I want to write a python code where given a string from user

`s = "hello, caps lock people of caps lock stackoverflow !"`

and should return `"hello, PEOPLE of STACKOVERFLOW !"`

> Note: PEOPLE Aand STACKOVERFLOW are uppercase.

Cant figure how to do this. please help!

Comment: This can be done with regular expressions (see module "re").

Comment: Sir/Mam I did google before posting here. @TheOracle.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution without regular expression. @MichaelButscher

Comment: It can be done without regular expressions with the "find" method for str objects but this is more complicated.

Comment: Yes it is complex thats why I asked. Would appreciate if you can provide the solution..

Comment: No, try it yourself first. You will learn a lot about string handling and Python. If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here then.

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `re.sub` with a callback function:

```
def to_upper(match):
    return match.group(1).upper()

s = "hello, caps lock people of caps lock stackoverflow !"
out = re.sub(r'\bcaps lock (\S+)', to_upper, s)
print(out)
```

This prints:

```
hello, PEOPLE of STACKOVERFLOW !
```

The approach here is to use `re.sub` to find every occurrence of `caps lock` followed by some word.  Then, this word match is passed to the callback function `to_upper()` which then returns the uppercase version as the replacement.